# IEnumerable methods

Tags: c#

I found this example in a C# book, can someone explain why can you pass the Fibs method into the EvenNumbersOnly method when it only expects a list?

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (int fib in EvenNumbersOnly (Fibs(6)))
        Console.WriteLine (fib);
}

static IEnumerable<int> Fibs (int fibCount)
{
   for (int i = 0, prevFib = 1, curFib = 1; i < fibCount; i++)
   { 
        yield return prevFib;
        int newFib = prevFib+curFib;
        prevFib = curFib;
        curFib = newFib;
   }
}

static IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbersOnly (IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
   foreach (int x in sequence)
       if ((x % 2) == 0) {
        yield return x;
       }    
}
```

Comment: As @alex said you are not passing the method, but the erturn value of a call to the method.  To pass the method, the syntax would look like this:  `foreach (int fib in EvenNumbersOnly(Fibs) )`,   without the parentheses or parameter value (the 6). and this would not work, (as you say), because `EvenNumbersOnly` can not accept a function delegate as an input parameter.

Comment: ok i get get it, another thing is why does the foreach in EvenNumbersOnly call Fibs, i get this in debug mode

Comment: because Fibs is not returning result immediately, but merely giving a proxy object that generates ints one by one. This is how "yield" works.

Comment: Your title is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

It expects `IEnumerable<int>` , as parameter type clearly states. And you are passing result of executing the method, not the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code int `Main` method is equivalent to this:

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> values = Fibs(6);

    foreach (int fibValue in EvenNumbersOnly(values))
        Console.WriteLine (fibValue);
}
```

So `Fibs` method is not passed to the `EvenNumbersOnly` method.